# Когда можно склеивать операторы ++ и +?

Tags: c++, операторы

```cpp
int x, y;

int main() {
    x++ + ++y;
    x+++  ++y;
    x++  +++y;
    x +++++ y;
}
```

Почему эта программа не выдаёт ошибок для 1 и 2 строки, но выдаёт их для 3 и 4?

> error: lvalue required as increment operand

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Первая строка будет разбита на токены следующим образом:

`x`, `++`, `+`, `++`, `y`, `;`.

Что в итоге даст *expression statement* с валидным выражением (постфиксный инкремент `x`, префиксный инкремент `y` и бинарный оператор сложения).

---

Вторая строка разобьётся на токены аналогично первой строке, потому что *preprocessing tokens*<sup>†</sup> вычисляются по принципу [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch), а максимальным валидным *предварительным токеном* будет `++`, а не `+++`.

[[lex.pptoken]/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.pptoken#3.3):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
> given character:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - Otherwise, **the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token**, even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail, except that a *header-name* ([[lex.header]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.header)) is only formed
>
>   - ...
>   - ...

---

Третья строка будет разбита на токены следующим образом:

`x`, `++`, `++`, `+`, `y`, `;`.

Отличие от первой и второй строки потому, что после 3-его базового символа `+` нет *whitespace* символов, которые в предыдущих случаях разделяли *предварительные токены* `+` и `++`.

В итоге получаем *expression statement* с невалидным выражением, т.к. к результату постфиксного инкремента применяется постфиксный инкремент.

[[expr.post.incr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.post.incr#1):

> ... The operand shall be a modifiable **lvalue**. ...
>
> The result is a **prvalue**. ...

---

Четвёртая строка разобьётся на токены аналогично третьей строке, потому что:

- *whitespace* символы после `x` и перед `y` не влияют на вычисление *предварительных токенов*;
- отсутствие *whitespace* символов после 2-ого базового символа `+` не влияет на вычисление *предварительных токенов* аналогично 1 и 2 строкам.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Подробнее о фазах трансляции можно почитать [тут](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/lex.phases). Тогда станет понятно, зачем разделять предварительные и обычные токены.</sup>